# ASP.NET Web API POST sending a VM and returning other VM

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to call API sending a viewmodel and receive back another one, using HttpClient.PutAsync, unsuccessfully.

My API works fine running PostMan, but it's a disaster in Xamarin.Forms (PostAsync stops working and the controls is sent back to calling method, I mean, It is terminated not even getting handled by "catch")

What is the proper way to do that? Thanks in advance.

My C# class:

```
public class MyNecessaryService
{
    private const string wsUrl = "https://my-ws-uri/api/blahblahblah;

    public async Task<OutputViewModel> PleaseDoIt(InputViewModel input)
    {
        OutputViewModel output = new OutputViewModel();

        try
        {
            // let's get started
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            // turns "my input view model" into JSON format
            var jsonConvert = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);

            // parameters is part of HTTP request
            var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonConvert);

            // "please send me a JSON"
            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            // do it now, please
            var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(wsUrl,httpContent);

            // ------ hellgate ------
            // PostAsync call never reach this line, neither the "catch" parts.
            // It jumps FTL back to calling async method ...

            var isSuccessStatusCode = httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode;

            // if the response contains stuff I'd like to read ...
            if (isSuccessStatusCode && httpResponseMessage.Content != null)
            {
                // ...get my content, ...
                var responseContent = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // ...turns JSON into "my output view model"
                output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutputViewModel>(responseContent);
            }

        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WebException =======> " + wex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception =======> " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // nothing for a while...
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

The Calling method:

```
    public async Task<OutputViewModel> GetMyData(InputViewModel input)
    {
        // ... declarations and decision making ....

        var service = new MyNecessaryService();
        output = await service.PleaseDoIt(input);

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks just fine to me. I use this method in my Xamarin.Forms project and it works just fine. How do you call the Method?

Comment: Hallo Benedikt, I've edited the question, showing the call. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you be more specific about the error instead of just "it's a disaster"

Comment: PostAsync stops working and the controls is sent back to calling method, I mean, It is terminated not even getting handled by "catch". Thanks!

Comment: What is `isSuccessStatusCode`? Is it (successful), and if not (not an exception)....?

Comment: @MarlonDias show higher up the call stack. There may be a blocking call (`.Result or .Wait()`) that may be causing the issue. What is calling `GetMyData`

Comment: What is the platform you are targeting and did you try to clean up your project and rebuild it?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! You opened my mind and I've found the problem... a blocking problem...

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!
The API was called from a blocking Command Button.

Reviewing the stack:

A XAML Page has some entries for the Input and a Button:

```
    <Entry ... />
    <Entry ... />
    <Button Text="GetData" Command="{Binding GetDataCommand}"/>
```

The PageViewModel has the Button Command to get the data from the API:

```
    private Command command;
    public ICommand GetDataCommand
    {
        get
        {
            getDataCommand = command ?? new Command(DoCommand, CanExecute);
            return command;
        }
    }
```

This method, called from Command, must be awaitable.
Otherwise the API call will be blocked.

```
    private async void DoCommand()
    {
        // ... prepare input model and call GetMyData ...

        output = await GetMyData(input);  // not blocking anymore...

        // ... go on and show next Page
    }
```